# PHP CodeIgniter WHERE clause statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a very basic statement that I am trying to run and I am have a problem.

```
$item = $this->db
            ->select("r.CustomerIDs, r.DateAdded")
            ->join("customer_orders_rewards as cor", "r.RewardID = cor.RewardID")
            ->join("customer_orders as co", "co.OrderID = cor.OrderID")
            ->where(array("r.Denomination" => $row['Denomination'], "r.RewardID" => "cor.RewardID"))
            ->get("customer_rewards as r");
```

In the statement above, it is interpreting `cor.RewardID` as a string where I want it to be a field from the `join`.

It is causing the query to look like this:

```
SELECT `r`.`CustomerID`, `r`.`DateAdded` 
FROM `customer_rewards` as `r` 

JOIN `customer_orders_rewards` as `cor` 
ON `r`.`RewardID` = `cor`.`RewardID` 

JOIN `customer_orders` as `co` 
ON `co`.`OrderID` = `cor`.`OrderID` 

WHERE `r`.`Denomination` = '35' 
AND `r`.`RewardID` = 'cor.RewardID'  <---- Issue
```

How can I reference a field from the `join` in my `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I was re-checking your query looking for changes (that maybe this case should be in the `join`), but turns out it already is - so that condition seems redundant to me. You are already joining the rows on that condition. Do you really need it in the `where`?

Comment: @FirstOne Well shoot, this question may have be unnecessary after all. I took that line out and it appears to still work. Thanks for setting me straight :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround is to use

```
"r.RewardID = cor.RewardID"
```

*instead of*

```
"r.RewardID" => "cor.RewardID"
```

That way, `cor.RewardID` shouldn't be treated as a string literal, but as an actual column.

---

On a side note, you're already joining rows when `r.RewardID = cor.RewardID`, so I'd say that extra condition is redundant (the problematic one), making it not needed.